# Flickr API: Receiving <err code="100" msg="Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)" /> on image upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, flickr, ng-file-upload

I am trying to figure out how I should approach image upload differently in order to receive a successful response in my Angular app.

First, I am using the **ng-file-upload** module to handle users uploading multiple images at once and some of the other functionality of the module. When a user selects a file for upload, the file is stored in an object with the following attributes (added an image of it from my console): 
[image of file object attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SFie.jpg)

Sending this file object as the image parameter using Imgur's image upload function worked successfully, so I don't think the issue is with the image file object. But maybe I'm wrong?

The following function is my call to Flickr's API to upload an image, which contains comments to better clarify the proccess: http://pastebin.com/3LFJKEtV

As I mention in the pastebin, I've tried using two methods for uploading. First, Angular's post method, passing it the request URL and the photo file as the data parameter. I also tried using the Upload.upload and Upload.http methods provided by ng-file-upload's upload service. In this case as well, I've used the built request URL, as well as the photo file as the data parameter.

However, in both instances, I am receiving "Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)". I've read various threads on this issue, but haven't been able to figure it out. If anyone could provide any insight or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate. Please let me know if you need me to clarify any part of my approach.

Comment: Upload.http() should be like this `Upload.http({
  url: '/server/upload/url',
  headers : {
    'Content-Type': file.type
  },
  data: file
})`

Comment: You have wrong data. Also from the error seems like the flickr api is expecting a key header, so you probably need to add more header frields to the request.